# How can I create this shape (template) in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, template

If you can point me to a tutorial that creates this shape, that would be great.
The curve section is whats giving me problems.

I need it to be scaleable and of course ability to insert my photos into it.

Thanks in advance, I also have illustrator but I think this can be made in photoshop.[image]

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!  Can you please show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Pen Tool to make a vector shape layer, fill it with white, put your photo layers underneath the shape layer.

Apply rectangular layer masks to the photos.

[image: Screenshot showing shape layer and photos with layer masks]